# 2 targets cant run on the same device

Tags: xcode, cordova, targets

I'm using xcode 4.6.3 and phonegap 2.8.1. I duplicated the target to have one for a free version of my app.
Problem is that when trying to install both of the targets on the iPhone simulator or on my own iPhone, I can't seem to get this to work.
This happens ONLY during the **first time I try to install the second target**.
Strange.. would appreciate anyones help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to share my solution inorder for the others to know. After creating two target using [this guide](http://xperienced.com.pl/blog/building-lite-version-in-5-easy-steps), than I creates a index2.html, and place it next to the original index.html. This one will server the free version. In AppDelegate.m I've used the `#ifdef` form the guide to determine if this is the free version, and changed it to index2.html file. Works perfect.